# How to create a class that will store a tuple of (r,g,b)?

Tags: python, class, tuples

**requirements:**

Create a class called "Color" that will store a tuple of (r,g,b).

The tuple should be stored in a data member called color.

The components of the color tuple should be stored in data members: red, green, blue as well

Add a str method to print out the color class so it looks like: "(red: redVal, green: greenVal, blue: blueVal)"

This is what I have so far

```
class Color():
def __init__(self,color):

def __str__(self):
    pass


if __name__=='__main__':
color = ()
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't here to do your work for you. You have to at least show some effort.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Post the code you have tried. We are not here to code for you, but to help solve the problems you facing while coding solution on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Color(object):
    def __init__(self,color):
        self.color = color
        r,g,b = self.color
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return "(red: {}, green: {}, blue: {})".format(self.r, self.g, self.b)


if __name__=='__main__':
    color = Color ((150, 100, 55))
    print color
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!